# Omission of the "helpan" «tio» and commas separating clauses

Tags: correlatives, subordinate-clauses, punctuation

Jen tiu frazo ekzempla.

> Mi vidis tion, ke la monado ŝtelis la lastan pilon.

La «tion» ja povas esti mankigita.

> Mi vidis, ke la monado ŝtelis la lastan pilon.

Sed ĉu ankaŭ la komo, laŭ la gramatiko?

> Mi vidis ke la monado ŝtelis la lastan pilon.

La [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/skribo/helposignoj.html) implicas tiel (t.e. ne estas ajna regulo deviga pri helposignoj), sed kio pri reala uzado kutima? Tio estas, eĉ se gramatike ĝuste, kiom ofta / kutima / komprenebla / akceptebla / ktp estus ĉiu el tiuj? Mi havas senton, ke la plejparto de parolantoj skribus la duan (t.e. sen "helpa" «tio[n]», sed kun komo). Malgraŭe, mia kutimo estas ĉiam aldoni kaj "helpan" «tio[n]» kaj komon, por "reguleco / perpendikulareco".

Teĥnnike, mi jam scias la solvan respondon, kiu probable estus tio, ke aŭ tute ne gravas aŭ nur iom**et**e gravas, kondiĉe, ke tio, kio estas dirita, estas sufiĉe komprenebla.

Parenteze, tiu lasta frazo mem eble havas tro multe da komoj. Kiel ankoraŭ plia ekzemplo en tiu ĉi demandafiŝo mem, eble anstataŭe povus esti dirita:

> Teĥnnike, mi jam scias la solvan respondon, kiu probable estus ke aŭ tute ne gravas aŭ nur iom**et**e gravas, kondiĉe ke kio estas dirita estas sufiĉe komprenebla.

Denove, probable estas tute senprobleme tiel diri tion, sed mi nur scivolas tion, kio estas pli / malpli [mal]ofta / [mal]kutima / [mal]komprenebla / [mal]akceptebla en Esperanto skribita nuntempa.

Donotan dankon monadan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Mi redaktis 2020-08-22 laŭ observo de das-g.)

**Helpa *tio* en *ke*-frazoj**

PMEG havas [ĉapitron](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/ke/subjekto.html#i-fj4) pri *ke*-frazoj kiel subjekto, temo de la ĉeffrazo. Oni povas uzi tielnomitan aldonon **helpa** *tio* por klarigi aŭ emfazi. Gramatike ĝi estas senbezona.

- Ĉu estas vera, ke li mortigis sin? (neŭtrala)
- Ĉu tio estas vera, ke li mortigis sin? (emfaza)

**Forlaso de ti-vorto en rilataj subfrazoj**

Rilata afero estas forlaso de TI-vortoj antaŭ rilataj subfrazoj. Oni konstatas en [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/ti-forlaso.html), ke oni kelkfoje povas forlasi tiajn TI-vortojn. Vi povas forlasi, se

- ti- kaj ki-vortoj apartenas al la sama grupo: tio–kio, tiu–kiu ktp.
- ti- kaj ki-vortoj havas la saman gramatikan kazon, aŭ la nominativon aŭ la akuzativon: tio–kio, tion–kion, tiu–kiu, tiun–kiun ktp.
- ne estas prepozicio antaŭ la ti-vorto

Ekzemple

- Tio, kio pasis, ne revenos. → Kio pasis, ne revenos.

**Komo**

Ne ekzistas devigaj reguloj pri la uzo de la komo. La baza regulo estas svaga: kiam oni bezonas paŭzi aŭ ia similan. Mi pensas, ke multaj uzas komon laŭ la reguloj de sia denaska lingvo. Mi konfesas, ke mi estas unu el tiuj, do ekz. ĉiam antaŭ subfrazoj, kiuj devas enhavi neinfinitivan verbon.

Comment: Parenteze, kio estas dirita pri «tio» en la kazo de io, kiel "Mi ne scias [tion], kiel"?
t.e. "I don't know how"
Mi ofte vidas tion, ke personoj dirus "Mi ne scias, kiel", jen sen jen kun komo, sed kio pri la laŭdire "helpa" «tio»? Ĉu tiu respondo implicas tion, ke oni tion ne povas fari?

Comment: Fakte mi ne certas. La verbo _scii_ povas havi ke-subfrazon kiel objekto: "Mi scias, ke…" Kiam temas pri demandaj subfrazoj, mi trovis kelkajn ekzemplojn en PMEG: "Ŝi ne sciis, ĉu ŝi…", "Mi ankaŭ ne scias, per kio oni…", "Ŝi ne sciis, en kiu flanko…" Verŝajne kiel-demandaj subfrazoj taŭgas kiel objekto sen helpa tio. Notu, ke en la frazo "Mi efektive jam ne scias, kiel ĝin klarigi" temas pri [mallongigita subfrazo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/kvazau_chefverboj.html), sed ankaŭ ĉifoje ne estas helpa tio.